# PopUp View after Camera Intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, popupwindow

So I was trying to build a Dialog you get after you have taken a photo via an Intent. The thing now is, when I have taken the picture the app crashes with following:

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: ur.mi.android.wgplus05, PID: 31616
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {ur.mi.android.wgplus05/ur.mi.android.wgplus05.PictureActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.IBinder android.view.View.getWindowToken()' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3706)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3749)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.IBinder android.view.View.getWindowToken()' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:995)
                                                                        at ur.mi.android.wgplus05.PictureActivity.showPopupImage(PictureActivity.java:195)
                                                                        at ur.mi.android.wgplus05.PictureActivity.onActivityResult(PictureActivity.java:174)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6508)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3702)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3749) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

The thing is when i outline the showPopUp() method, it works fine. But i've already used this popup in other methods so i thought it would work here again... Long talking heres my code:

```
  public class PictureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
private Camera camera;
private FotoItemAdapter listAdapter;
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_CAMERA = 1;
private FrameLayout mainLayout;
private ArrayList<FotoItem> posts;
private ImageAdapter gridAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fotowand);
    initCamera();
    initPostList();
    initUI();

}

private void initCamera() {
    camera = new Camera(this);
}

private void initPostList() {
    posts = new ArrayList<>();
}

private void initUI() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_foto_wand);
    Point displaySize = getDisplaySize();

    GridView grid = new GridView(getApplicationContext());
    gridAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, displaySize);
    grid.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_foto_item);
    listAdapter = new FotoItemAdapter(this,posts);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.photo_add_button) {
        checkPermission();


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_CAMERA:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                takePicture();
            } else {

            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

private void checkPermission() {
    int permissionCheckCamera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    int permissionCheckWriteExStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheckWriteExStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED || permissionCheckCamera == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

            Log.d("photo", "permission ist nicht da ");

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_CAMERA);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.

        }
        else Log.d("photo", "permission ist schon da "); takePicture();
    }




private void takePicture() {
    Log.d("photo", "*photo*");
    camera.takePicture(REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

private void processPicture(String path) {
    Point imageSize = new Point(getDisplaySize().x, getDisplaySize().y);
    Bitmap image = camera.getScaledBitmap(path, imageSize);

    gridAdapter.addImage(image);
    gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



}

private Point getDisplaySize() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        processPicture(camera.getCurrentPhotoPath());
        Log.d("foto",Integer.toString(requestCode)+" "+ Integer.toString(resultCode));
    }
        showPopupImage();
}


public void showPopupImage() {

    // get a reference to the already created main layout


    // inflate the layout of the popup window
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_popup_image, null);

    // create the popup window
    int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    boolean focusable = true; // lets taps outside the popup also dismiss it
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);


    // show the popup window
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); //thats line 195!


    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.foto_image_popup);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(gridAdapter.getItem(0));

    final EditText editText = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.foto_edit_commentary_popup);

    final Button buttonAdd = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.foto_button_popup);




    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FotoItem fotoItem = new FotoItem(editText.getText().toString(), gridAdapter.getItem(0));
            posts.add(fotoItem);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            popupWindow.dismiss();

        }
    });
}


}
```

Hope you can help me! Thank you already:)

Comment: `mainLayout` is null because you call `mainLayout=findViewById(...);` before `setContentView(...);`

Comment: Maybe call `initUI()`  just before assigning `mainLayout`

Comment: @ElvisChweya you we re completely right! Thats what you get when u you sit on it too long :) Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. God knows how many times I've been bitten by these bugs too. Cheers!